# Should I capitalise the first letter when a sentence starts with a number?

Tags: capitalization, numbers, writing-style

When starting a sentence with a number, should the first letter be capitalised?

For example,

> 96% **R**eal meat.

or

> 96% **r**eal meat.

Comment: Numbers count as capital letters when starting sentences. SInce they don't distinguish upper- and lower-case, they can be used at any time, like a `Get Out Of Jail Free` card.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since you ask about sentences that begin with a number, it seems relevant to note that many style guides advise against using a numeral at the beginning of a sentence. And if you spell out the opening number as a word, the question of whether the next word in the sentence should be capitalized doesn't come up. Here are some stylebook guidelines on this question.

From *The New York Times Manual of Stye and Usage* (1999):

> In ordinary news copy, spell any number that begins a sentence: *Five hundred delegates attended*.

From *The Associated Press Stylebook and Briefing on Media Law* (2002):

> SENTENCE START: Spell out a numeral at the beginning of a sentence. If necessary, recast the sentence. There is one exception—a numeral that identifies a calendar year.
>
> Wrong: *993 freshmen entered the college last year.*
>
> Right: *Last year 993 freshmen entered the college.*
>
> Right: *1976 was a very good year.*

From *The Chicago Manual of Style*, fifteenth edition (2003):

> **9.5** *Number beginning a sentence.* When a number begins a sentence, it is always spelled out. To avoid awkwardness, a sentence should be recast.
>
> [Examples:] One hundred and ten candidates were accepted. (*And* may be omitted.)
>
> or
>
> In all, 110 candidates were accepted.

From *Words Into Type*, third edition (1974):

> **Beginning a sentence.** A numeral should not stand at the beginning of a sentence. A number so placed should be spelled out or the sentence reworded to bring the number elsewhere in the sentence.
>
> *Wrong*: $36,000 was the amount of the debt.
>
> *Right*: The amount of the debt was $36,000.
>
> *Wrong*: 1941 saw our entry into the war.
>
> *Right*: The year 1941 saw our entry into the war.

From *The Oxford Guide to Style* (2002):

> Use words for all numbers at the beginning of sentences; to avoid spelling out cumbersome numbers, recast the sentence or use periphrasis, for example *The year 1849* instead of *Eighteen forty-nine*.

The way you handle numbers at the beginning of sentences remains a style decision, but the style guides I consulted showed a remarkable degree of unanimity in favoring spelling out the number in that situation. The only dissenter on this point is the *AP Stylebook*, which recommends spelling years with numerals even at the beginning of a sentence. It bears observing that in its example of a sentence starting with a year—"1976 was a very good year"—AP rendered the second word, *was*, in all-lowercase letters.

Whether this advice applies to sentence fragments such as "96% real meat" is for you or your publisher to decide. If I were posting a fragment such as that one on, say, a butcher shop price card, I would feel free to please myself on number-versus-word, capitalization, and punctuation.

Comment: +1 agreed on last paragraph.  many examples i've seen give the entire fragment in uppercase, bypassing the issue altogether.  [case in point](https://www.google.com/search?q=100%25+natural&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=paVJVdXTFI79oQT27YD4DA&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1403&bih=729).

Comment: The *real* question is what's the remaining 4% meat? Artificial?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: The remaining 4 percent falls under the general heading "wannabe meat."